# add NA for a value based on a condition, with tidyverse only, R

Tags: r, tidyverse, na

I have age variable with very odd numbers such as 1000, 6666. Now obviously this data is bad for any analysis. I want to keep the obvious age, but want to replace weird numbers with NA. For example, 0, 1,2,3 4, ... 100, I shall keep. But from >100 I want to put them as NA. Yet, want this only with tidyverse. I looked int several functions like na_if for example but cannot achieve what I want.

This is an example of data I have. Look at row 66 and you will see what I am talking about.

```
age_dput <- structure(list(Age = c(63, 19, 23, 28, 40, 31, 60, 26, 35, 44, 
    30, 47, 26, 45, 21, 38, 40, 28, 26, 40, 60, 33, 72, 40, 32, 32, 
    43, 24, 25, 39, 50, 22, 37, 53, 51, 42, 52, 29, 19, 42, 58, 61, 
    29, 26, 45, 29, 20, 26, 28, 43, 2, 42, 40, 33, 43, 53, 55, 27, 
    36, 41, 30, 54, 55, 6222, 21, 26, 38, 23, 48, 29, 44, 42, 35, 
    27, 28, 20, 59, 80, 35, 36, 24, 29, 34, 31, 25, 37, 30, 31, 48, 
    28, 30, 65, 45, 27, 39, 29, 34, 29, 76, 40)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), problems = structure(list(
        row = c(2910L, 35958L), col = c("how_unwell", "how_unwell"
        ), expected = c("a double", "a double"), actual = c("How Unwell", 
        "How Unwell"), file = c("'/Users/gabrielburcea/Rprojects/data/data_lev_categorical_no_sev.csv'", 
        "'/Users/gabrielburcea/Rprojects/data/data_lev_categorical_no_sev.csv'"
        )), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    )))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `replace` or `if_else` :

```
library(dplyr)
age_dput %>%
  mutate(clean_age_replace = replace(Age, Age > 100, NA_real_), 
         clean_age_if_else = if_else(Age > 100, NA_real_, Age))
```

Comment: thanks Ronak. it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Using `na_if()`:

```
library(dplyr)
age_dput %>% 
  mutate(Age = na_if(Age, Age[Age > 100]))
```